# json2html, I need to add click events to the resulting html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, json2html

json2html, I need to add click events to the resulting html after the transform.  right now I am using a timer. Even though it did not appear to be an option i attempted to add the code to the Options for the transform call. Didn't work.  Is there a better option than adding a timer to document.ready to give the transform time to run before adding my click event to the resulting divs?

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.item').click( function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $.fancybox({
      height: '100%',
      href: $this.find('a').attr('href'),
      type: 'iframe',
      width: '600px'
    });
    return false;
  });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

this answer is coming a little late .. but hey better late than never.

You can directly assign events within json2html like so

[json2html eventData example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313664/json2html-eventdata-example)

OR you can just do it manually after you call the transform like so

```
$('#someElement).json2html(data,transform);

$('.item').click( function() {
   $this = $(this);
   $.fancybox({
      height: '100%',
      href: $this.find('a').attr('href'),
      type: 'iframe',
      width: '600px'
   });
   return false;
});
```